# Create a DataFrame which is made of all pairs of rows from another

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, time-complexity

I have a DF which has two columns: questions and answers. The answers column contains duplicates.

I would now like to create a new DF which has three columns: question1, question2, duplicate.

The question1 and question2 columns will be populated as every unique combination of all questions in the initial DF. The duplicate column will be booleans corresponding to whether or not the questions have the same answer in the initial DF.

The initial DF is ~13,000 rows, and so the resulting DF will be large (I presume far too large for Pandas on my machine, but I can reduce the initial DF for testing and then change to something other than pandas if I need all the data).

Is there a way to this anyway quicker than an O(N^2) nested loop as such as this takes far too long without parallelisation/vectorisation:

```
questions1, questions2, duplicates = [], [], []

for i in range(len(dataset)-1):
    print(f'{i+1} / {len(dataset)-1}')
    question1 = dataset.iloc[i]['question']
    answer1 = dataset.iloc[i]['answer']
    for j in range(i+1, len(dataset)):
        question2 = dataset.iloc[j]['question']
        answer2 = dataset.iloc[j]['answer']
        duplicate = answer1 == answer2
        questions1.append(question1)
        questions2.append(question2)
        duplicates.append(duplicate)

duplicate_dataset = pd.DataFrame({
    'question1': questions1,
    'question2': questions2,
    'duplicate': duplicates
})
```

**EDIT:** As requested, here is a toy sample of input DF:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'question': ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'pqr', 'stu', 'vwx', 'yzz'],
    'answer': ['1', '2', '1', '3', '4', '4', '5', '1', '6']
})
```

And the resulting DF should be equal to this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'question1': [
        'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc',
        'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc',
        'def', 'def', 'def', 'def',
        'def', 'def', 'def', 'ghi',
        'ghi', 'ghi', 'ghi', 'ghi',
        'ghi', 'jkl', 'jkl', 'jkl',
        'jkl', 'jkl', 'mno', 'mno',
        'mno', 'mno', 'pqr', 'pqr',
        'pqr', 'stu', 'stu', 'vwx'
    ],
    'question2': [
        'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno',
        'pqr', 'stu', 'vwx', 'yzz',
        'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'pqr',
        'stu', 'vwx', 'yzz', 'jkl',
        'mno', 'pqr', 'stu', 'vwx',
        'yzz', 'mno', 'pqr', 'stu',
        'vwx', 'yzz', 'pqr', 'stu',
        'vwx', 'yzz', 'stu', 'vwx',
        'yzz', 'vwx', 'yzz', 'yzz'
    ],
    'duplicate': [
        False, True, False, False,
        False, False, True, False,
        False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, True,
        False, False, False, False,
        False, False, True, False,
        False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False
    ]
})
```

Comment: if u provide some data, it could help get responses faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another solution, which still relies on [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip). 

Lump df.question and df.answer, use combinations to create non repeated pairs, use a list comprehension to get the pairing of True or False and finally create a new dataframe with the output.

```
from itertools import combinations
#zip columns, then combine
M = (combinations(zip(df.question,df.answer),2))

#list comprehension here to get ur True or False entries
outcome = [(i[0],j[0],True) 
            if i[-1]==j[-1] else (i[0],j[0],False) 
            for i, j in M]

 #create new dataframe
new_df = pd.DataFrame(outcome,columns= ['question1','question2','duplicate'])
```

Comment: Worked and was impressively quick

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do with using [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
from itertools import combinations

# Create mapping Series of questions - answers
q_map = df.drop_duplicates(subset='question').set_index('question')['answer']

# Create DataFrame of all combinations of questions
df2 = pd.DataFrame(combinations(df['question'].unique(), 2), columns=['question1', 'question2'])

# Create duplicate field using the helper mapping Series
df2['duplicate'] = df2['question1'].map(q_map) == df2['question2'].map(q_map)
```

[out]

```
   question1 question2  duplicate
0        abc       def      False
1        abc       ghi       True
2        abc       jkl      False
3        abc       mno      False
4        abc       pqr      False
5        abc       stu      False
6        abc       vwx       True
7        abc       yzz      False
8        def       ghi      False
9        def       jkl      False
10       def       mno      False
11       def       pqr      False
12       def       stu      False
13       def       vwx      False
14       def       yzz      False
15       ghi       jkl      False
16       ghi       mno      False
17       ghi       pqr      False
18       ghi       stu      False
19       ghi       vwx       True
20       ghi       yzz      False
21       jkl       mno      False
22       jkl       pqr      False
23       jkl       stu      False
24       jkl       vwx      False
25       jkl       yzz      False
26       mno       pqr       True
27       mno       stu      False
28       mno       vwx      False
29       mno       yzz      False
30       pqr       stu      False
31       pqr       vwx      False
32       pqr       yzz      False
33       stu       vwx      False
34       stu       yzz      False
35       vwx       yzz      False
```

Comment: This threw this exception for me: `pandas.core.indexes.base.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects` on the final line.

Comment: Your questions in original data frame can’t be unique I think

Comment: I've updated the solution, should just be a simple case of adding a `drop_duplicates` to the `q_map` helper Series